# WPF - Binding data template

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik

I'm trying to bind `<DataTemplate>` on Telerik RadDiagram ShapeStyle:

```
<telerik:RadDiagram x:Name="Diagram"
                            ShapeStyle="{StaticResource NodeStyle}"
                            GraphSource="{Binding GraphSource}"/>
```

This style looks like this:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="NodeStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadDiagramShape">
            <Setter Property="Position" Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="Geometry" Value="{telerik:CommonShape ShapeType=RectangleShape}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StyleConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
                        <Binding Path=""/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
...
</Grid.Resources>
```

StyleConverter:

```
class StyleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        FrameworkElement targetElement = values[0] as FrameworkElement;

        if (values[0] is BilledMsisdnViewModel)
            return targetElement.FindResource("BilledMsisdnControl");
        else if(values[0] is BilledImeiViewModel)
            return targetElement.FindResource("ImeiControl");

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Those resources (BilledMsisdnControl and ImeiControl) are defined in `<UserControl.Resources>`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:BilledMsisdnControl x:Key="BilledMsisdnControl"/>
        <local:ImeiControl x:Key="ImeiControl"/>
        <local:StyleConverter x:Key="StyleConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And they are created by me user controls.

So my goal here is according to binded view model type select user controll (this part works) and then use it as `ContentTemplate` (this don't work). I'm getting just object namespace nad name for ImeiControl or BilledMsisdnControl in diagram node.
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddiagram/howto/mvvm-style-selectors) you should use style selector

```
public class NodeStyleSelector : StyleSelector 
{ 
    public Style BilledMsisdnStyle { get; set; } 
    public Style BilledImeiStyle { get; set; } 
 
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container) 
    { 
        if (item is BilledMsisdnViewModel) 
            return BilledMsisdnStyle; 
        else if (item is BilledImeiViewModel) 
            return BilledImeiStyle; 
        else return base.SelectStyle(item, container); 
    } 
}
```

Define styles with `ContentTemplate`. Inside `ContentTemplate` add your user controls.

```
<Style x:Key="BilledMsisdnStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadDiagramShape">
    <Setter Property="Position" Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
    <Setter Property="Geometry" Value="{telerik:CommonShape ShapeType=RectangleShape}" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
        <Setter.Value> 
            <DataTemplate> 
                <local:BilledMsisdnControl/> 
            </DataTemplate> 
        </Setter.Value> 
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style x:Key="BilledImeiStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadDiagramShape">
    <Setter Property="Position" Value="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}" />
    <Setter Property="Geometry" Value="{telerik:CommonShape ShapeType=RectangleShape}" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
        <Setter.Value> 
            <DataTemplate> 
                <local:ImeiControl/> 
            </DataTemplate> 
        </Setter.Value> 
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Add shape style selector

```
<styleselectors:NodeStyleSelector x:Key="CustomShapeStyleSelector" 
                BilledMsisdnStyle="{StaticResource BilledMsisdnStyle}" 
                BilledImeiStyle="{StaticResource BilledImeiStyle}" />
```

Use `ShapeStyleSelector` for your `RadDiagram`.

```
<telerik:RadDiagram x:Name="Diagram"
                        ShapeStyleSelector="{StaticResource CustomShapeStyleSelecto}"
                        GraphSource="{Binding GraphSource}"/>
```